# Is William Blake's usage of "to break a net" idiomatic or metaphorical?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms, history, metaphors

The following passage is from William Blake's 1793 work "[The Marriage of Heaven and Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marriage_of_Heaven_and_Hell)":

> A man carried a monkey about for a shew, & because he was a little wiser than the monkey, grew vain, and conciev'd himself as much wiser than seven men. It is so with Swedenborg: he shews the folly of churches & exposes hypocrites, till he imagines that all are religious, & himself the single one on earth that ever **broke a net**.

What is the meaning of the phrase "to break a net" used there? Is it a metaphor of some sort, or is it some idiom that has fallen by the wayside as English developed over the past 220 years? If it is an idiom, what is its history, and if it is a metaphor, what exactly is the action of "breaking a net" supposed to be? My guess is that it has something to do with fishing, but I'm not sure what (to be clear: should the phrase be a metaphor, I would like to know what comparison the metaphor is actually making, not the interpretation of what that comparison means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joseph Viscomi](http://englishcomplit.unc.edu/people/viscomij) writes in his ["The Lessons of Swedenborg; or, The Origin of William Blake's *The Marraige of Heaven and Hell*"](http://books.google.com/books?id=lCKv0KHHN8EC&lpg=PA187&dq=%22broke%20a%20net%22&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false) that Blake is attacking Swedenborg's naivety for "thinking oneself singular--or free of Religion's entangling net" (p. 187). Using Viscomi's interpretation, we can infer that the metaphor of breaking a net (picture a fish breaking through a fisherman's net) is an implied comparison to Swedenborg's claim to have written something new or "to have broken from 'the religious'" (p. 187).